# page by click link in another page in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have one doubt can i have an anchor tag in demo1.html page if i click that link it has to got to demo2.html page. In demo2.html page i am using a data filter and it has to select that filter can we do like that. Here is the sample code i amm using

demo1.html

```
 <li>
    <div><a href="urunlist.html?dataType=ahsap">
    <h2>Ahşap Panel</h2>
    <p>Doğal Ağaç Görünümlü Duvar Kaplama Panelleri, Doğada var olan dokuları estetik bir incelikle
                        duvarlarınıza yansıtın. Ham ağaç olan duvarların dokusunu yeniden keşfedeceksiniz.</p>
     </a></div>
 </li>
```

demo2.html

```
<'--Tab filter-->
    <div class="build">
                <ul id="filterOptions" class="clearfix">
                    <li class="cur"><a class="Hepsi btn btn-link linear" href="#">Hepsi </a></li>
                    <li style="top:5px;"><span>/</span></li>
                    <li><a class="tas btn btn-link linear" href="#">Taş Plakalar</a></li>
                    <li><span>/</span></li>
                    <li><a class="ahsap btn btn-link linear" href="#">Ahşap Plakalar</a></li>
                    <li><span>/</span></li>
                    <li><a class="tugla btn btn-link linear" href="#">Tuğla Plakalar</a></li>
                    <li><span>/</span></li>
                    <li><a class="beton btn btn-link linear" href="#">Beton Plakalar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

<!--Filter Block-->
            <ul class="container_folio clearfix gallery">



         <li class="box" data-id="id-1" data-type="tas">
                        <div class="folio-img build">
                            <div class="portfolio-item ">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                   <div class="thumb-img">
                                   <a href="image/tasplakalar/001-2-b.jpg" data-gal="prettyPhoto[gallery2]" title="Taş Panel Atolyesi">
                                    <img class="linear img-portfolio img-responsive" src="image/tasplakalar/001-2-b.jpg" alt="Tas Panel R-001">
                                   </a>

                                   <div class="folio-caption animated">
                                       <p>Taş Panel R-001</p>

                                   </div>
                                   </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </li>   
        <li class="box" data-id="id-27" data-type="ahsap">
                        <div class="folio-img build">
                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <div class="thumb-img">
                                        <a href="image/ahsapplakalar/015-b.jpg" data-gal="prettyPhoto[gallery2]"
                                           title="Taş Panel Atolyesi">
                                            <img class="linear img-portfolio img-responsive" src="image/ahsapplakalar/015-b.jpg"
                                                 alt="Ahşap Panel R-015">
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="link"><a href="#">Taş Panel Atolyesi</a></div>
                                        <div class="folio-caption">
                                            <p>Ahşap Panel R-015</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li> 
    </ul>
demo2.html javascript

    <script>
            function getParameterByName(name) {
                name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
                var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
                        results = regex.exec(location.search);
                return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
            }

        </script>

        <script language="JavaScript">
            $('li.box').filter(function () {
                return $(this).attr('data-type') == getParameterByName('dataType');
            }).addClass('cur');
        </script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVshm.png)

Comment: you mean at page load you have to select something on basis of your parameter

Comment: '<div><a href="urunlist.html?dataType=ahsap">'
to  '<li class="box" data-id="id-1" data-type="ahsap">'  help me please

Comment: so whats the error ? your code is ok. I have doubt about the dataType ! is there any `li` with `dataType=ahasp` exists in your second page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Yes** you can do like that having an `anchor` in one page and pass a `parameter` to other page and do filtering on the basis of `url`.
>
> **Note**: Make sure you have the `filters` available in second page so that you can select on basis of your **url** parameter.

**Also** you haven't wrap your code inside `DOM ready`, your filter will not work because it will not find that `li` on which your filtering, because your **DOM** is not ready yet.

**Snippet**

```js
$(function(){
   var filter = 'ahsap'; // URL parameter
    $('li.box').each(function () {
       var type = $(this).attr("data-type"); 
      if( type == filter ){
      $(this).addClass("cur");
      }
    });
  
  $("#filterOptions li").each(function () {
       var type = $(this).find("a").attr("data-type"); 
      if( type == filter ){
      $(this).addClass("cur");
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
.cur{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="build">
                <ul id="filterOptions" class="clearfix">
                    <li><a class="Hepsi btn btn-link linear" href="#" data-type="hepsi">Hepsi </a></li>
                    <li style="top:5px;"><span>/</span></li>
                    <li><a class="tas btn btn-link linear" href="#" datat-type="tas">Taş Plakalar</a></li>
                    <li><span>/</span></li>
                    <li><a class="ahsap btn btn-link linear" href="#" data-type="ahsap">Ahşap Plakalar</a></li>
                    <li><span>/</span></li>
                    <li><a class="tugla btn btn-link linear" href="#">Tuğla Plakalar</a></li>
                    <li><span>/</span></li>
                    <li><a class="beton btn btn-link linear" href="#">Beton Plakalar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

<!--Filter Block-->
            <ul class="container_folio clearfix gallery">



         <li class="box" data-id="id-1" data-type="tas">
                        <div class="folio-img build">
                            <div class="portfolio-item ">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                   <div class="thumb-img">
                                   <a href="image/tasplakalar/001-2-b.jpg" data-gal="prettyPhoto[gallery2]" title="Taş Panel Atolyesi">
                                    <img class="linear img-portfolio img-responsive" src="image/tasplakalar/001-2-b.jpg" alt="Tas Panel R-001">
                                   </a>

                                   <div class="folio-caption animated">
                                       <p>Taş Panel R-001</p>

                                   </div>
                                   </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </li>   
        <li class="box" data-id="id-27" data-type="ahsap">
                        <div class="folio-img build">
                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <div class="thumb-img">
                                        <a href="image/ahsapplakalar/015-b.jpg" data-gal="prettyPhoto[gallery2]"
                                           title="Taş Panel Atolyesi">
                                            <img class="linear img-portfolio img-responsive" src="image/ahsapplakalar/015-b.jpg"
                                                 alt="Ahşap Panel R-015">
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="link"><a href="#">Taş Panel Atolyesi</a></div>
                                        <div class="folio-caption">
                                            <p>Ahşap Panel R-015</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li> 
    </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. but it did not .

Comment: @KadirGÜNEY check snippet i think thats what you wanted.

Comment: It did not happen again. I added pictures.

Comment: Add that filter block  in html

Comment: i don't know what u wana do, i updated my snippet thats how far i understand what you want.

Comment: Thank you. Mark is now doing. :). but how can I do the filtering process. I am using this https://codyhouse.co/demo/content-filter/index.html plugin. kindly help me out with this

Comment: Sure I will but I dont know about cody house filtering. So I have to see the documentation and that will take time. If my answer helps you then accept it.

Comment: Thank you very much. will wait for your reply.